# Can I use empathic do with verb to be?

Tags: word-choice

I've generally seen emphatic `do` being used with verbs other than `to be`. But I've just come across a phrase where I felt like saying `do are`, and I don't know if 1) that's correct English, and 2) that sounds good.

The phrase would be:

> Notice no default constructor will be generated because there is a user-declared one; but the rest of the special member functions **do are** automatically generated.

In case `do are` is not correct/doesn't sound good there, what other options would I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Do are" is not correct. Even using the bare infinitive "do be" is incorrect.

In speech you should emphasise with a stress on the word "are", in writing you should use italics, or underline, to emphasise.

> the rest of the special member functions *are* automatically generated.

There are forms of the verb "to be" which allow or require do support:  In a imperative "Do be kind" or "Don't be evil".

Comment: The 'but' is usually a sufficient hint.

Comment: You could also use an adverbial phrase such as “are indeed” or “definitely are.”

Comment: @JamesK Many thanks for the edit, the quick, clear and precise response, and for distinguishing between speech and writing. I was focusing on writing when I post the question and forgetting about speech.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Correct. That's true.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Many thanks. I thought about `are indeed` but, I don't know why, I liked my `do are` more.

Answer (score 3):

*Do* as an auxiliary is **always always always** followed by the base form of the verb, so in the rare cases where this construction is possible, it is *do be*, not *do are*.

*Be* does not normally take *do* support in any context; but there are a few partial exceptions:

- There are some varieties of English, such as some West country dialects from England, where you hear *He do be...*; but not in any standard varieties.
- In the negative imperative, it is normal to use "do"-support: "Don't be angry" is the only grammatical form in modern English. ("Be not angry" is obsolete, and only used as a deliberate archaism).
- In the non-negative imperative, we sometimes use "do"-support for emotional effect. *Do be quiet* and *Do be careful* are variants of *Be quiet* and *Be careful*, which tend to be used with family and friends, and have an emotional connotation: *Do be quiet* is usually annoyed, though it may be indulgent or jokey; *Do be careful* expresses caring for the person, but sometimes annoyance as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response. `Do + base form of the verb` was something that I had completely bypassed.